# ActiveRecord query with table alias in from field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can I make this query into a scope in rails 3.2? 
The point is to access two different table entries and pick info that is common to both of them.

```
SELECT u1.FirstName, u2.FirstName
FROM User AS u1, User AS u2
WHERE u2.LastName=u1.LastName
```

Do you know other way to achieve this with better performance?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question, you can do this:

```
User.joins('join users as u2 on users.last_name = u2.last_name and users.id != u2.id')
```

This will give you all the users that have the same last name as any other user.

Comment: Yes was exactly that, i also achieved the same result with a different approach using: 

    User.from("Users as u1, Users as u2).where("u2.LastName=u1.LastName")